# How do I update web.config webServer.Handler section programatically?

Tags: asp.net, webforms, web-config

I'm using Asp.Net web forms.

I would like to be able to update the web.config file automatically. I know it can be done, but I'm not sure every section can be updated or how to achieve it.

Here's the section I'm interested in:

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
     <handlers>
      <add name="MainSitemap" path="sitemap.xml" verb="GET" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I'm trying to add the handler.

I've done some research and can get so far, but essentially, I don't know how to create the handler itself.

Here's the code I'm working with:

```
        var configuration = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~");
        var section = (what should this cast be?)configuration.GetSection("system.webServer/handlers");
        var action1 = new HttpHandlerAction("sitemap.xml", "System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler", "GET");
        section.Handlers.Add(action1);
        configuration.Save();
```

Questions:

- What should I cast the section to?
- Is add HttpHandler correct?
- How do I add the name and precondition parts?

It's not exactly intuitive so would appreciate any advice.

Comment: Why do you want to modify the handler configuration at runtime? What is it you hope to accomplish by doing that?

Comment: I don't want to modify it, I want to add it. The code above would be inside a "CMS" project rather than the website itself. Alternatively, I could just add the handler to the website, but then the routing (which is managed in the project), would be separated.

Comment: I would not adopt a system in which web.config is to be modifed. I would use a database or some other means here. If you modify web.config, IIS (internet services) will detect this, and re-start the app-pool. (in effect a re-start of the web site. This will often (if not always) cause things like session() to be lost, and more hairy scary things. If you have sql server based sessions, then they probably will survive. I would try rather hard to avoid having to modify web config, since IIS will have to re-load it, and that re-starts your app-pool. In effect, IIS has to re-load + re-configure

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal I absolutely get where you're coming from. However, the idea is that this would be set on application startup, so all of those things you mentioned should probably happen anyway. It's not as if modification is going to happen randomly out of the blue. That said, the only reason these handlers exist is to give a normal routed aspx file an dot xml extension, which isn't strictly necessary, so I will probably look at other options.